# How to change datatype from xs:string to strongly types in Biztalk schema?

Tags: biztalk

I need to have a datatype of Amount (reference) for my Amount field. How to change that? Now I just get the normal datatypes (xs:string, xs:double, etc), but the existing fields are strongly typed like this - **Datatype : Amount (Reference)**. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you need to import your reference schema and set the data type to the Amount field defined within it.

If that's the case, you can do that by;
a) selecting you the  node
b) Selecting the Import property in the Property Window
c) Leave the 2Import new schema as:" option as XSD Import and click "Add..."
d) Point to your reference schema.

You should be able to set the data type of your amount field to the refernce type now.

HTH